# How to make criteria on the year part of a timestamp attribute?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "demandefraismission")
public class DemandeFraisMission extends BaseModele {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private int id;
   
   //  ...

   @Column(name = "datevalidation")
   private Timestamp datevalidation;

   //  ...
}
    
@Override
public List<DemandeFraisMission> listeDmdValidatedAnneeAvant(String site, String anneeAvantValidation) {
   List<DemandeFraisMission> retour = null;
   try {
      Session session = null;
      if (entityManager == null
          || (session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)) == null) {
                    throw new NullPointerException();
      }
      Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DemandeFraisMission.class, "i");
      criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("i.lieumission", site));
      criteria.add(Restrictions.like("i.datevalidation", anneeAvantValidation, MatchMode.START));
      criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("i.status", "Validée"));
      criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
      retour = criteria.list();
      System.out.println(retour);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   return retour;
}
```

How to make a criteria on the `datevalidation` attribute but just on the year part of the timestamp value?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this:

```java
import org.hibernate.type.IntegerType;

// ...
Integer expectedYear = 2020;

// ...
criteria.add(
   Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
      "EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datevalidation) = ?",
      expectedYear,
      IntegerType.INSTANCE
   )
)
```

See [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-narrowing) of hibernate documentation.

The `EXTRACT()` function is a SQL standard function supported by MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, and Firebird. If you use SQL Server, you can use the `YEAR()` or `DATEPART()` function to extract the year from a date.